# Is there a doAfterSubscribe equivalent in RxJava2?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an observable that streams responses to all requests.  I'm wanting to create a filter of that observable when a request is made so that I can share the output with multiple subscribers.  Following is some example code.

```
    PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<String> fooObservable = publishSubject.filter(value -> value.startsWith("foo"))
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                publishSubject.onNext("foobar");
            })
            .replay(1)
            .refCount();

    fooObservable.subscribe(val -> log.info("A val : <{}>", val));
```

I'm using a PublishSubject as my mock service because sometimes the service will return a response immediately.

What I'm finding is that because there is no current subscription when there is an immediate result my fooObservable is not being populated. i.e. I get no log output when I want to see :

```
A val : <foobar>
```

Note that I get the same result with this code :

```
PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> fooObservable = publishSubject.filter(value -> value.startsWith("foo"))
        .replay(1)
        .refCount();

publishSubject.onNext("foobar");
fooObservable.subscribe(val -> log.info("A val : <{}>", val));
```

So the issue is that the fooObservable doesn't subscribe to the PublishSubject until after it has been subscribed to,

Is there a way to run code immediately after the first subscription to the fooObservable?

Edit:
I thought about something like :

```
PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
BehaviorSubject<String> fooObservable = BehaviorSubject.create();
publishSubject.filter(value -> value.startsWith("foo")).subscribe(fooObservable);
publishSubject.onNext("foobar");
fooObservable.subscribe(val -> log.info("A val : <{}>", val));
```

But then I've got 2 subscriptions and I'm not sure how to clean up as the subscribe after the filter does not return a disposable.

Edit 2 : A description of the background task.

I have a third party service that my code needs to subscribe to.  This service calls an onResponse method in my code with a parameter containing my original request and the response.  The response may be updated by a new call to onResponse at any time.

I want to wrap to create a wrapper for this service that provides a method:

```
public Observable<Response> getObservable(Request req);
```

If the request matches one that is already subscribed then the observable should provide the most recent matching value immediately on subscription.

When there are no subscribers I need to unsubscribe from the service I'm wrapping.

Comment: Curious, how come you want to bind the emission of the value to the subscription event? Why not use something like `BehaviorSubject` as your mock service? You could just call `BehaviorSubject.onNext(...)` and it will emit that value to subsequent subscribers.

Comment: @Trogdor : Are you suggesting I replace fooObservable with a BehaviourSubject?  If so the question edit is my problem with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think `publish()` and `connect()` are what you need. [Here](https://medium.com/@satoshun/about-rxjava-connectable-observable-e3905a432f8e) you can read more about it.

In your case it's gonna be something like:

```
PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> fooObservable = publishSubject
    .filter(value -> value.startsWith("foo"))
    .publish();

fooObservable.subscribe(val -> log.info("A val : <{}>", val));
Observable<Object> o2 = fooObservable.map { new Object() }
Observable<Object> o3 = fooObservable.map { /* Something here*/ }

Disposable disposable = fooObservable.connect()
```

But remember to do `disposable.dispose()` to not have leak

**EDIT**

```
BehaviorSubject<String> publishSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
Observable<String> fooObservable = publishSubject.filter(value ->         
value.startsWith("foo"));
fooObservable.subscribe(val -> log.info("A val : <{}>", val));
publishSubject.onNext("foobar");
```

Comment: Does not seem to work,.  Now it misses all updates sent before both subscribe and connect have been called.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson How is it possible? Do you do `publishSubject.onNext(...)` somewhere before `fooObservable.connect()`? Where?

Comment: The onNext is called by a non rx service in response to a subscription request.  Under some circumstances thus may happen synchronously.  The subscription to this service should only happen once which is why i thought an 'afterSubscribe' on a shared observable might be a good place to do the subscribe.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson then i guess the only way for is to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `PublishSubject ` (not instead of `Observable `), so it will "repeat" last population for every new subscriber.

Comment: That's one of the options I considered.  Any ideas how I'd clean up the suscription in the edit section of my question?

Comment: @PeterWilkinson , no i meant you need to get read of PublishSubject at all. See edit in my unswear

Comment: That won't work for me as I need to store the most recent value that passes my filter.  If I cache at the top level then only one filter will ever match.  I also get too much data to be able to just replay every response.  I've added a 2nd edit to my question to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest edit of the question helps explain what you're trying to do and this GitHub link probably has the answer you're looking for:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4675

But I'll still share my test code. I ended up following the advice from the link above and using `PublishSubject` with `.replay(1).refCount()`.

Let's say we have a third-party service interface:

```
interface ThirdPartyService
{
    void subscribe( Consumer<Integer> responseConsumer );

    void unsubscribe();
}
```

Next let's create a mock implementation that will invoke the consumer with a random int until it unsubscribes:

```
    // Mock service to emit a random integer once per second, no Rx:
    ThirdPartyService mockService = new ThirdPartyService() {

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        @Override
        public void subscribe( Consumer<Integer> responseConsumer )
        {
            System.out.println( "Subscribe" );
            Random random = new Random();

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    int i = random.nextInt( 10 );
                    System.out.println( "Producing: " + i );
                    responseConsumer.accept( i );
                }
            };

            timer.schedule( task, 1000, 1000 );
        }

        @Override
        public void unsubscribe()
        {
            System.out.println( "Unsubscribe" );
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };
```

Next, the actual Rx pipeline. Let's say I want to filter only odd integers and unsubscribe from service when there are no observers:

```
    // Wrap service in a PublishSubject:
    PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    mockService.subscribe( subject::onNext );

    // Create observable:
    Observable<Integer> observable = subject
            .doFinally( mockService::unsubscribe )
            .filter( i -> i % 2 == 1 )  // Include only odd integers
            .replay( 1 )                // Replay latest to new observers
            .refCount();
```

Finally, a manual test:

```
    // Subscribe to Observable:
    Disposable sub1 = observable.subscribe( i -> System.out.println( "sub1 got: " + i ));

    // Sleep:
    Thread.sleep( 3300 );

    // Create 2nd Subscriber:
    System.out.println( "adding sub2" );
    Disposable sub2 = observable.subscribe( i -> System.out.println( "sub2 got: " + i ));

    // Sleep:
    Thread.sleep( 3300 );

    // Dispose 2nd Subscriber:
    System.out.println( "disposing sub2" );
    sub2.dispose();

    // Sleep:
    Thread.sleep( 3300 );

    // Dispose 1st Subscriber:
    sub1.dispose();

    // Sleep:
    Thread.sleep( 3300 );
```

Output:

```
Subscribe
Producing: 1
sub1 got: 1
Producing: 8
Producing: 6
adding sub2
sub2 got: 1
Producing: 3
sub1 got: 3
sub2 got: 3
Producing: 7
sub1 got: 7
sub2 got: 7
Producing: 1
sub1 got: 1
sub2 got: 1
disposing sub2
Producing: 6
Producing: 7
sub1 got: 7
Producing: 1
sub1 got: 1
Unsubscribe
```